# PHP Filter partially matched array elements

Tags: php, preg-match, array-filter

I have an array that contains multiple elements (URL's) that have a similar name.

I am using `array_filter` in order to filter elements that contain a specific string.

```
$urls = $images;
$string = 'books-for-kids';

$images= array_filter( $urls, function( $url ) use ( $string ) {
    return ( stripos( $url, $string ) !== FALSE );
});
```

Below is the output:

```
    array(126) { 
        [51]=>  string(103) “http://www.example.com/books-for-kids-to-print-90” 
        [52]=>  string(107) “http://www.example.com/free-books-for-kids-to-print-1” 
   }
```

Since the string i'm filtering is in both URL's it's matching them both. 
However this is not the output i'm looking for. I'm just looking to match the first URL.

I'm not really sure how do that, but was thinking maybe to use regex to match "/string-[0-9]" (backslash string dash any number) this way it will only match first URL.

Comment: Are you wanting to match the string at the beginning of any path segment, or only at the beginning of the last segment? (e.g. match `http://www.example.com/books-for-kids-to-read/more/path`?)

Comment: when you are filtering array, `return` inside the closure uses for detecting whether or not to include element to resulting array. you can just use `$images[0]` after using filter, or find and return first matched element via `foreach` plus `if`

Comment: Why the first and not second?  You need to define rules.

Comment: I'm looking to match URL's that only contains the string i'm looking for (i.e. books-for-kids-to-print). if it matched books-for-kids-to-print-"Any Number" its ok, but not books-for-kids-to-print-download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You guess right. You could use regex:

```
$images = array_filter($urls, function($url) use ($string) {
    return preg_match("~^.*/$string(-\d+)?/?$~", $url);
});
```

The regex looks for the last path to contain `$string` with an optional leading `-[0-9]` pattern. So a URL like `http://localhost/path/sub-path/YOUR-STRING-01/` will pass.

Note: If `$string` comes from an untrusted source do a `preg_quote()` on it.

Comment: This makes sense, but I'm getting an empty array.

Comment: I assumed `$string` contains `books-for-kids-to-print`. If that's not right then we need a minor modification.

Comment: The url looks http://www.example.com/books-for-kids-to-print-90, just the example is the domain name. $string does contain books-for-kids-to-print.

Comment: You can try to run this.  <?php $string = "books-for-kids-to-print";
$urls = array ("http://www.example.com/books-for-kids-to-print-90");

//var_dump ($urls);

$images = array_filter($urls, function($url) use ($string) {
    return preg_match("~^.*/$string(-\d+)?/?$~", $url);
 
 var_dump ($images);
}); ?>

Comment: If you `var_dump($images);` you'll see the right output. What's wrong?

Comment: Thank you! I found my mistake! i was using var_dump($images); inside the function.  Is it possible to match urls that end with an extension? for example  example.com/books-for-kids-to-print-90.jpg or gif?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, it is. Add `\.\w+` after matching the digits.